# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, rubygems, spotify

I'm new to ruby on rails and currently working on a web application which uses the 'rspotify' gem to interact with the Spotify API.

I have a controller called 'genre' which I use to direct my search results from the index page. However, it won't let me initialize any variables inside the index function.

This is what my controller looks like

```
# genre_controller.rb
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @genres = RSpotify::Recommendations.generate(limit: 20, seed_genres: ['country'])
      # render :json => @songs
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

This is what my my index page looks like

```
<h1>Genre#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/genre/index.html.erb</p>

<h1 class="page-header">Music Matching <%= params[:search] %></h1>
<ul>
 <% @music.each do |music| %>
   <li><%= music.name %> | <%= link_to "Show", genre_path(music.id) %></li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is what my routes look like

```
  get 'genre/index'
  get 'genre/show', to:'genre#show', as: 'genre'

  get 'site/index'
  root 'site#index'
```

I get an error on line 4 of my genre controller, where I call the RSpotify method. Any variable I try to instantiate there returns a NoErrorMethod.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

Here's the exception I get from the console

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/genre_controller.rb:4:in `index'
Started GET "/genre/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=hello" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-19 16:14:59 -0800
Processing by GenreController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"hello"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms
```

Here's the full tracestack from the exception

```
rspotify (1.27.0) lib/rspotify/recommendations.rb:101:in `initialize'
rspotify (1.27.0) lib/rspotify/recommendations.rb:97:in `new'
rspotify (1.27.0) lib/rspotify/recommendations.rb:97:in `generate'
app/controllers/genre_controller.rb:4:in `index'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Please add full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: edited to add the stacktrace from the exception, sorry!

Comment: Judging from the code RSPOTIFY.get returns nil https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/blob/master/lib/rspotify/recommendations.rb

Comment: I suggest figuring out how to enable RestClient wire logs and look at what Spotify returns in response.

Comment: Are you authenticating your client prior to making this request?

Comment: I do not see the declaration of the @music variable, will it be that you did not declare it? admitting that you did not declare the varariable the error is logical.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error as above when I tried to connect to the Spotify API. The documentation on rspotify missed out the fact that you need to run the authenticate method before you do anything with the API.

i.e.

```
RSpotify.authenticate("<your_client_id>", "<your_client_secret>")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - you're right, the docs don't mention you need to auth before working with any of the API. This fixed it for me too. Thanks!